# Using Preg Match to check if string contains an underscore

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to check if a string contains an underscore - can anyone explain whats wrong with the following code

```
    $str = '12_322';
    if (preg_match('/^[1-9]+[_]$/', $str)) {
       echo 'contains number underscore';
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're not trying to find out if a string contains an underscore, but a number underscore. Change the echo to 'contains number underscore'. Use a string util function to find out if a certain character exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your regex `[_]$` means the underscore is at the end of the string. That's why it is not matching with yours.

If you want to check only underscore checking anywhere at the string, then:

```
if (preg_match('/_/', $str)) {
```

If you want to check string must be comprised with numbers and underscores, then

```
if (preg_match('/^[1-9_]+$/', $str)) {  // its 1-9 you mentioned
```

But for your sample input `12_322`, this one can be handy too:

```
if (preg_match('/^[1-9]+_[1-9]+$/', $str)) {
```

Comment: Just as an addition for case 1 (only checking if '_' is in string) - `strpos` will be faster than regex.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `$` out since underscore is not the last character in your input. You can try this regex:

```
'/^[1-9]+_/'
```

**PS:** Underscore is not a special regex character hence doesn't need to be in character class.